# Is Empire Total War compatible with 64-bit OS?

Tags: empire-total-war

ETW is an old game so I was wondering if it runs on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes.  Empire Total War should be compatible with Windows 7 64-bit OS.  There have been some issues with crashes and some other issues that I believe have been solved, but just in case you run into some crash problem you can visit [here](https://forums.totalwar.com/discussion/169961/random-crashes-on-windows-7-x64-fixed).